# Why the "isValid" boolean is not updating its value, even though the Log statement is executing properly inside this coroutine scope

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

```
private fun getuser() {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(binding?.emailLogin?.editText?.text.toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(binding?.passwordLogin?.editText?.text.toString())){
            var isvalid = false
            CoroutineScope(Default).launch {
                userlist = userViewModel.allusersList()
                val email = binding?.emailLogin?.editText?.text.toString()
                val pass = binding?.passwordLogin?.editText?.text.toString()
                for(user in userlist){
                    if(user.name == email && user.pass == pass){
                        Log.d("Validity", "Valid User")
                        isvalid = true
                    }
                }
            }
if(isvalid){
   Toast.makeText(this@Login_Fragment.requireContext(), "Valid 
    User",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            
      }
        
    }

}
```

So my question here is can we update any variable's value (which is declared outside the scope of coroutine's) inside the coroutine's scope?

Comment: Yes you can, but you’re checking the value of isValid before the coroutine has time to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency problem. By the time the control is in `if(isvalid){` line the data has not come back from the coroutine scope ..you need to use a with context block for eg

```
    private fun getuser() {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(binding?.emailLogin?.editText?.text.toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(binding?.passwordLogin?.editText?.text.toString())){
                var isvalid = false
                CoroutineScope(Default).launch {
                    userlist = userViewModel.allusersList()
                    val email = binding?.emailLogin?.editText?.text.toString()
                    val pass = binding?.passwordLogin?.editText?.text.toString()
                    for(user in userlist){
                        if(user.name == email && user.pass == pass){
                            Log.d("Validity", "Valid User")
                            isvalid = true
                        }
                    }
                     withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
    if(isvalid){
       Toast.makeText(this@Login_Fragment.requireContext(), "Valid 
        User",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                
          }
    }
                }
    
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: it's saying that I have to make the getUser() function to be a suspend function

Comment: although i got a solution, we can do like this: - if(isvalid){
                    activity?.runOnUiThread {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@Login_Fragment.requireContext(),
                            "Valid User",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                }

Comment: you're using kotlin so using the main dispatcher is better.:)